# How Migrate Room database by destroying and reloading database from assets

Tags: android, android-sqlite, database-migration, android-room

I am using [Android Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) for my app database. I need to change the version from 1 to 2, and the correct .db is embedded in my app folder `assets/databases/`

I can either specify a migration method with `addMigrations()` or use `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()`

`fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` empty my database and I don't know how to populate it again from the one in my folder `assets/databases/`. Maybe can I specify a callback when fallbackToDestructiveMigration happens ?

If I add a migration method, there is too many differences between expected & found, plus I don't know how to set some COLUMN as "NOT NULL".

> Expected:
>       TableInfo{name='poi', columns={sound_path=Column{name='sound_path', type='TEXT',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   name_FR=Column{name='name_FR', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, text_FR=Column{name='text_FR',
>   type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   address=Column{name='address', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, city=Column{name='city',
>   type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   text_EN=Column{name='text_EN', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   video_path=Column{name='video_path', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   opening_hour=Column{name='opening_hour', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   img_360_paths=Column{name='img_360_paths', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   open_schedule_EN=Column{name='open_schedule_EN', type='TEXT',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   closed_days=Column{name='closed_days', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   open_schedule_FR=Column{name='open_schedule_FR', type='TEXT',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   category_id=Column{name='category_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
>   notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   img_paths=Column{name='img_paths', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   closing_hour=Column{name='closing_hour', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, price=Column{name='price',
>   type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   game_path=Column{name='game_path', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, can_skip=Column{name='can_skip',
>   type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true,
>   primaryKeyPosition=1}, closed_months=Column{name='closed_months',
>   type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   vr_path=Column{name='vr_path', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, name_EN=Column{name='name_EN',
>   type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}},
>   foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
>        Found: 08-09 17:27:47.990 22583-22583/com.rendrsoftworks.vrlib E/AndroidRuntime: TableInfo{name='poi',
>   columns={sound_path=Column{name='sound_path', type='TEXT',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   name_FR=Column{name='name_FR', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, text_FR=Column{name='text_FR',
>   type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   address=Column{name='address', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, city=Column{name='city',
>   type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   text_EN=Column{name='text_EN', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   video_path=Column{name='video_path', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   opening_hour=Column{name='opening_hour', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   img_360_paths=Column{name='img_360_paths', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   open_schedule_EN=Column{name='open_schedule_EN', type='TEXT',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   closed_days=Column{name='closed_days', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   open_schedule_FR=Column{name='open_schedule_FR', type='TEXT',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   category_id=Column{name='category_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   img_paths=Column{name='img_paths', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   closing_hour=Column{name='closing_hour', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, price=Column{name='price',
>   type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   game_path=Column{name='game_path', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, can_skip=Column{name='can_skip',
>   type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false,
>   primaryKeyPosition=1}, closed_months=Column{name='closed_months',
>   type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   vr_path=Column{name='vr_path', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, name_EN=Column{name='name_EN',
>   type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}},
>   foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same issue. You don't have to run these methods `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` or `addMigrations()`, at least not in the mentioned case. Simply just make the `poi` class same as db table and check the notations, for instance, your `poi` table as showing in the error message appears to have one different field which is in your `poi` class `"can_skip" notNull = true` whereas in your db table `"can_skip" notNull = false` so all what you have to do is to remove the annotation `@NonNull` it should be like this

`@ColumnInfo(name = "can_skip")
   // @NonNull remove this
    private int mCanSkip;`.

After that uninstall your app from the emulator or your phone and then rebuild and it will work fine.

**Helpers:**

[RoomSQLiteDifferenceFinder](https://hrankit.github.io/RoomSQLiteDifferenceFinder/): allows you to determine differences between db table and its class.

[DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/): allows you to manage your db easily.